how to update the azure alert status from slack
I have configured the logic app to send the azure alert rule triggered information to slack. i need to update the alert status as well from the slack, for example an alert got triggered i want to update the user response as acknowledged or resolved etc. how its possible.
Using this approach now to send the alert to slack using logic apps.
also while checking the triggered alert rule payload user response property also not available.


how to update the azure alert status

You can do that by adding extra property in Logic apps using below design:
After you receive an alert, taken custom basic alert, then added extra property using add property.

Output:

While Sending alert to slack, you can add acknowledgement property and send to slack. If you are sending alert from slack, after receiving you can add the property. But from slack you cannot add the acknowledgement directly.  For further information on Sending message to slack.
